# Does Firebase Database has any protection against spam users by default?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firebase Cloud Firestore for Android, I need to prevent spam read and write in database. I'm working on package booking app, so the user may use a bot to book a package continuosly, then it will increase my billing.

Is there any solution?

Comment: To ensure all access to your database is authorized, have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Comment: There is a chance authenticated users can also make a spam!

Comment: Is there anyway to prevent number of writes to user per day?

Comment: See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/647, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46623063/firestore-limit-writing-access-per-time and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830079/firebase-rate-limiting-in-security-rules (which shows how to do this on Firebase's other database).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response.

Comment: I'm also interested.